# Can we directly import non-static methods without importing class (like we do for static methods)?

Tags: java, methods, import, static, instance

For static methods, I can import directly e.g.:
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

Is it applicable for non-static/instance methods also?

Comment: You need an instance to call an instance method. As long as you have an instance, you can call that method, so the import list is irrelevant. I'm not sure what you are asking. It'd be clearer if you can show an example of how you'd like to call instance methods.

Comment: "RestAssured" is a class and we have static method named "given" in it. In usual cases, we import the class and press ctrl+space to show all the methods present in this class. 
So we can directly import static methods, without importing class using "import static" keyword in java.
So, if there is any non-static method/s in the class, then, same thing can be applied to non-static methods too? I mean, could we import non-static methods too, without importing the class.

Comment: Even if importing non-static methods would be possible like `import Foo.nonStaticMethod;` what do you want to achieve by it? Do you want to shorten your code so insead of writing `fooInstance.nonStaticMethod()` you would write only `nonStaticMethod()`? **But how would compiler now know on which *instance* such method should be called**? Notice that there can be few instances of `Foo` class and unless you are calling method on `this` instance you *must* explicitly provide information on which instance method should be called. In Java it is done via `specificInstance.nonStaticMethodName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

An instance method requires an instance reference to operate on.  But once you have a reference to an instance you don't use a fully qualified name to call (or name) an instance method.  You just call it like as follows:

```
 obj.someMethod()    // or 
 this.someMethod()   // or
 someMethod()
```

In each case you just use the simple name of the method.  You don't need the class name, let alone the full class name.

<sup>Besides, if (hypothetically) instance method names *could* be statically imported, it would probably be rather confusing when reading code.   Just imagine what might happen if you imported `Object.equals` ... So it's probably **a good thing** it isn't allowed.</sup>

Since static imports of instance methods are neither generally meaningful or necessary ... and they are not supported.